# How to create a custom date time widget for the django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-widget, custom-widgets

**My Problem:**

I have a model that accepts `DateTimeField`. The user enters this from the `django-admin`. But, I cant get a way to get the user's local timezone. So my best shot is forcing the user to enter the date-time in `UTC`. But for the users convenience, I do not want him/her to calculate each time the offset and then the time in `UTC`. `Django` doesn't seem to provide a way of doing this.

**What I intend to do:**

I want to create a `custom widget` that will also let the user choose the `timezone` along with entering the `date` and `time`. For this I am using the `jQuery datetime picker.` I also intend to `override` the `django admin` form to have it use this widget of mine.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo by ioncache</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style type='text/css'>
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function(){
        $(function() {
            $('#date-time-tz').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss z',
            showTimezone: true,
            timezoneList: [
                {"value": "0", "label": "UTC"},
                {"value": "+60", "label": "FRANCE"},
                {"value": "+330", "label": "INDIA"},
                {"value": "-240", "label": "US EAST"},
                {"value": "-420", "label": "US SF"}
            ]
        });       
    });
    });//]]>  
    </script>

    </head>
        <body>
        <form name="time">
            <div style="margin: 15px;">
                <input id="date-time-tz" type="text" value="" name="date-time-tz">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

There isnt any `action` or `method` because I don't want this widget to `post` anything anywhere. What it simply does is brings out a nice `UI` in the browser and lets the user enter a `date-time` and `timezone`. So when the user clicks on `Done` in this `jQuery UI` the value appears in the `textbox` of the `form.`

**I seem to have hit a block. Cant think it out at all:**

I cant figure out anyway that will let me `reference` this `input` by its `id` or `name` inside my `widgets.py` file. `widgets.py` file is the file where I intend to `define` the `custom widget` by extending `Widget` from `*django.forms.widgets*`. I read through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget) and figured out that `Widget` class has two methods of particular importance in this case. The `render` and `value_from_data_dict` methods. The former to render the html template and the latter to extract that value from the data dict. (I may be wrong.) But I cant figure out any way to link these two parts of my code. I need help.

**Update:**

I worked on it but its not working. Heres what I have done till now:

**ui/admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
                "all": ("style/jquery-ui.css",
                        "style/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css",)
            }
        js = ("js/jquery-ui.js",
              "js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
              "js/tz_widget.js",)

    formfield_overrides = {
            models.DateTimeField : {'widget': TimezoneDate()},
        }
```

**widgets.py**

```
DATE_FORMAT = "%m-%d-%y"

class TimezoneDate(forms.widgets.Widget):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(TimezoneDate, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        if value is None:
            vstr = ''
        elif hasattr(value, 'strftime'):
            vstr = datetime_safe.new_datetime(value).stftime(DATE_FORMAT)
        else:
            vstr = value
        id = "%s" % name
        args = \
            "<input type=\"text\" value=\"%s\" name=\"%s\" id=\"date_time_tz\" />" % \
            (vstr, name)

        return mark_safe(u"\n".join(args))
```

And here is **tz_widget.js :**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#date-time-tz').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss z',
        showTimezone: true,
        timezoneList: [
            {"value": "0", "label": "UTC"},
            {"value": "+60", "label": "FRANCE"},
            {"value": "+330", "label": "INDIA"},
            {"value": "-240", "label": "US EAST"},
            {"value": "-420", "label": "US SF"}
        ]
    });       
});
});
```

What I am stuck at is how do I invoke the javascript from tz_widget.js? In the django admin there is no dropdown or anything. So I am sure the javascript function isnt being called. How can I call it? I dont think I can render it along the html unicode string. Any ideas? I have been at this all night. Need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a more generic widget.

First, separate your js, html and media for create a unique widget.

widgets.py

```
 class DatTimeField(forms.Textarea):
     def render(self, name, attrs = None):
         final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs,name=name)
         return "Here you have to return the html of your widget, for example: mark_safe(u'<input type=text %s value=%s class='your_css_class'/>' % (flatatt(final_attrs), value))"
```

Now in your admin class, try this:

```
class YourClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField : {'widget': DatTimeField()},

    }
```

If you want to customize your widgets, I suggest you to see the TinyMce widget Code. I know it's a way different but this code helped me to develop my own widgets (https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/tree/master/tinymce)

Django docs is also helpful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: shouldn't the class `DateTimeField` extend `Widget`?

Comment: You can do this way too. Like I sad, I based myself in tinymce widget, but you can do this some other ways, like this example here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget.format_output)

Comment: can you explain the html string that is returned? What is `flatatt` and what does `final_attrs` consist of?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta final_attrs is the attributes the widget will display in django style, like id=id_name_of_the_field and name=name_of_the_field, also some others attributes

Comment: flatatt -> Convert a dictionary of attributes in a string (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/util.py)