# Cant get Custom widget to work by replacing django's default date time widget in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-widget

I had asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584532/how-to-create-a-custom-date-time-widget-for-the-django-admin) but I think its dead. I even updated it with my progress. So after that I worked a little more with firebug for firefox and discovered some errors that make no sense to me. But before that heres my code: (My app name is `ui`)

**ui/admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
                "all": ("style/jquery-ui.css",
                        "style/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css",)
            }
        js = ("js/jquery-ui.js",
              "js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
              "js/tz_widget.js",)

    formfield_overrides = {
            models.DateTimeField : {'widget': TimezoneDate()},
        }
```

**widgets.py**

```
DATE_FORMAT = "%m-%d-%y"

class TimezoneDate(forms.widgets.Widget):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(TimezoneDate, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        if value is None:
            vstr = ''
        elif hasattr(value, 'strftime'):
            vstr = datetime_safe.new_datetime(value).stftime(DATE_FORMAT)
        else:
            vstr = value
        id = "%s" % name
        args = \
            "<input type=\"text\" value=\"%s\" name=\"%s\" id=\"date_time_tz\" />" % \
            (vstr, name)

        return mark_safe(u"\n".join(args))
```

**And here is tz_widget.js :**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#date-time-tz').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss z',
        showTimezone: true,
        timezoneList: [
            {"value": "0", "label": "UTC"},
            {"value": "+60", "label": "FRANCE"},
            {"value": "+330", "label": "INDIA"},
            {"value": "-240", "label": "US EAST"},
            {"value": "-420", "label": "US SF"}
        ]
    });       
});
});
```

So I want to replace the default date time widget of django by `jQuery UI datetime picker`
Now the `id` in the input field is `date_time_tz` the same id contained in `tz_widget.js`
I ran it as an independent file, where I included `tz_widget.js` in the `src` of my html file. It works. But in django it doesnt.

The errors:

TypeError: $ is undefined
tz_widget.js (Line 1) 
which is : `$(window).load(function(){`

TypeError: $ is undefined
js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js (Line 20)
which is : `$.ui.timepicker = $.ui.timepicker || {};`

I think its the same error that producing it in both the places. I am a little clueless. Heres a [link](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) to jQuery-UI-datetimepicker. Some guidance please?

**Update: **

I added this part into `widget.py` but still no widget in `HTML` source code.

```
class TimezoneDateForm(forms,Form):
    test = forms.DateTimeField(label="", widget=TimezoneDate())
```

Comment: I dont get it. What would be the admin view? I have to override that too? Didnt see it mentioned anywhere in any other SO answer for custom widgets.

Comment: What do you see when you render the widget? `>>> tz = TimeZoneDate()` 
`>>> tz.render('A name', 'A value')`

Comment: `>>> tz = TimezoneDate()
>>> tz.render('A name', 'A value')`
Output: 
`u'<input id="date_time_tz" type="text" value="A value" name="A name">'`

Comment: So you need to tell JS to work on `id=date_time_tz` not `id=date-time-tz` - see additional answer below.

Comment: Shit man! Thats really bad. :( Fixed that thanks!

Comment: @danodonovan There are more than one `date time fields`. like `from_time` `to_time` `last_updated`. But it only comes in one of them.

Comment: I got that working. Replaced the `#` by `.` Thus making it a `class` form an `id`. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `jQuery` widget you'll need to include the `jQuery.js` (or whatever name you have) core library file in your html header. The

```
TypeError: $ is undefined ...
```

makes it seem as if you might have forgotten to do that.

The `TimeZoneDate` widget is claiming the widget is called

```
id=\"date_time_tz\"
```

but the `js` is attempting to work with something called

```
$('#date-time-tz')
```

I'd suggest changing one or the other so that they match! Maybe in the widget;

```
id=\"date-time-tz\"
```

Comment: What does the HTML source code look like? Is the widget there?

Comment: No. No widget. I am using the correct id to reference. But still no widget.